# Strange thing with onmousemove javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse, onmousemove

[image]Hi guys:)If I pass on the div in the example with mouse's pointer the function print in console two times,this menans that onmousemove event is triggered two times.I have printed also the coordinates of mouse's pointer and how you can see in the image below,i don't move also verticallylly but only horizontally.How is possible that onmousemove event is triggered considered that the div is 1 pixel width?How is possible that onmousemove event is triggered two times considered that the div is 1 pixel width?

```
  <div id="div1">

</div>

#div1{
  height:200px;
  width:1px;
  background:red;

}


document.getElementById("div1").onmousemove= function(){

              console.log("in mousemove function");
              console.log(event.clientX);
              console.log(event.clientY);

             };
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind `onmousemove` which will be called every time the mouse is moved over the element. When you hover the div you sometimes move the mouse down resolving in additional calls to the handler.

It will be more clear if you add more width to the div.

What you properly wants is `onmouseenter` which will be called once when you enter the div:

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('mouse entered div');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the console.log to alert and you will notice that the event is fired only once. It works for me. I tried using the same code just that executed javascript on DOM ready.

I also changed the width to 20 pixels so as to be sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle of your example code: https://jsfiddle.net/jy8u4y2m/

You will notice that while your div is `1px` wide, it is also `200px` high. This means that if you enter the div with your mouse, `onmousemove` will be triggered. However, if you then move your mouse down before exiting the bounds of the div, the event will continue triggering. My assumption is that you are getting multiple calls because you aren't moving your mouse perfectly horizontal.

As @andlrc posted, if you want a single trigger, you should be using `mouseenter` instead.

Comment: No,It happens only when div is 1px width.If I put an higher width it won't happen,it means that I move perfectly horizontal my mouse also bacause when I see that the on mousemove event is triggered I move mouse's pointer out of the div:)

Comment: What do you mean it won't happen with a larger width? With a larger width you should get even more logs.

Comment: I put mouse's pointer whit high precision only in the first pixel of the div and if the div is 1 pixel on mousemove is triggered 2 times

Comment: Well on the fiddle above I only get a single trigger if I do that.

Comment: With 1 pixel wide div?

Comment: i forgot to say that i am using chrome

Comment: Yes with one pixel wide on chrome, I only get a single trigger.

Comment: i have updated my question with an image...in that image i didn't move vertically but onmousemove is triggered two times...it is very strange...